# Favicon shows on a browser tab but not on a bookmark in Firefox

Tags: html, firefox, favicon

As in the topic.

I created a 32x32 favicon.ico file and put it into a project folder.
This icon shows nicely on a browser's tab but when I drag this tab to bookmarks icon changes to a terminal icon.

I run page locally with flask development sever and Firefox.

I tried different locations and formats with the same effect.

I suspect some Firefox's settings needs to be changed because Chromium and PaleMoon are fine.

Any ideas where else to look?
This is just an annoyance but any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Do you locally use http or https? in my case it works with http but not with https. And this issue will not repro on production with a proper certificate.

Answer (score 2):

Favicons in firefox are loaded dynamically that is each time you open a tab, this has been a bug about it until recently [this](https://www.cs.uic.edu/%7Epolakis/papers/solomos-ndss21.pdf) study was released this showed that favicons are capable of tracking browsing activity as favicons are saved by other browsers to local disk, then firefox made it a feature ;).

Later [supercookie](https://github.com/jonasstrehle/supercookie) was released and showed the proof of concept working.

But to answer your question firefox loads then each time when connecting to the server which was a bug, which now is a feature to have the favicon retrieved opening eachtime.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of this. Very interesting. Nevertheless I run my app locally only and would like to have my icon showing with bookmark link. I mean other bookmarks I have do show icons and often I remove description leaving pic only on bookmark bar.

Comment: @Ranny there sure is a way, but I wanted to inform generally since firefox loads dynamically the way which works on most browsers won't work here. Someone might know it, accept that as answer.

Comment: It was valuable info, no doubt, and yet another reason to use FF over other populars. My problem still stands though. StackOverflow icon sits on my bookmark-bar but some others do not, even if they are on browser's tab.  How to force *my* favicon to get there?